# PDO - Prepared statement doesn't handle variable right

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a variable (`$q=$_GET["q"];`) that I want to run my prepared statement with. It contains a column name of my database table.

The value of the variable comes from a dropdown list. When I run the following code the output is the **exact value** that was chosen in the list. So it is just a column name.

```
$q=$_GET["q"];

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database";

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM repertoire";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($q));

    echo "<select>";
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() ) {
        echo "<option>";
        echo "{$row->{$q}}";
        echo "</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
```

However, When I change this line `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM repertoire";`

to `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ".$q." FROM repertoire";` the I get the desired rows from the database...

I'm not so good with PHP, so I guess that my syntax is wrong somewhere.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table name as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Comment: Can't help but wonder what kind of application needs to get tables and/or column names from user input whenever I see these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PDO, prepared statements prepare the values, not the tables.

You'll need to handle the user input and quote directly.

```
$q=$_GET["q"];

// Make sure you sanitize your user inputs using filter_inputs() or similar.

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database";

$colNames = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); // Create object for getting column names.
$sql = "DESC repertoire Field"; // SQL for getting column names.
$stmt = $colNames->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$colList = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0); // Fetch the results into $colList array.

if (in_array($q, $colList)) { // If the value of $q is inside array $colList, then run.

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $q FROM repertoire";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($q));

        echo "<select>";
        while ( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() ) {
            echo "<option>";
            echo "{$row->{$q}}";
            echo "</option>";
            }
        echo "</select>";
}
```

Also read: [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)

Edit: I've added a way to check to make sure $q is a valid column by basically doing a SQL desc in order to get all the column names out of table repertoire.

Comment: Alright, no fancy question mark here :)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Err, one reason you should use prepared statements (parametrized queries) is to prevent SQL injection. In this suggested answer, this is completely missing. Very bad example.

Comment: @hakre I had added a comment that the user input should be checked but didn't describe how. I've added a way to ensure that the input matches a valid table name. Good comment on the fact that user inputs should always be sanitized and checked.